# Aurelia CLI build failing on source maps

Tags: aurelia

Aurelia CLI build/run is producing the following error. Not too sure what the issue is.  **au build** or **au run** produces this message in the build log.  I did a fresh pull from the repo and ran **npm install.**

```
au run
Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'processFontAwesome'...
Starting 'copyFiles'...
Starting 'processGlyphicons'...
Starting 'processImages'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'copyFiles'
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processImages'
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildJavaScript'...
Finished 'processGlyphicons'
Finished 'processFontAwesome'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'buildJavaScript'
Starting 'writeBundles'...
Tracing app...
Tracing environment...
Tracing main...
Tracing actions/actions...
Tracing application/application...
Tracing chat/chat...
Tracing common/checkbox...
Tracing common/home...
Tracing customer/banking...
Tracing customer/employment...
Tracing customer/extended...
Tracing customer/income...
Tracing customer/personal...
Tracing customersnapshot/customerSnapshot...
Tracing flags/flags...
Tracing lead/banking...
Tracing lead/employment...
Tracing lead/extended...
Tracing lead/income...
Tracing lead/leadDisplay...
Tracing lead/personal...
Tracing loanmarks/loanMarks...
Tracing loans/loans...
Tracing login/login...
Tracing notes/notes...
Tracing resources/index...
Tracing savedbanks/savedBanks...
Tracing testFolder/testShowData...
Tracing tickets/tickets...
Tracing resources/attributes/datepicker...
Tracing resources/common/common...
Tracing resources/value-converters/currency-format...
Tracing resources/value-converters/date-format...
Tracing resources/value-converters/phone-format...
Tracing resources/value-converters/ssn-format...
Tracing resources/dialogs/previousAppDetails...
Tracing resources/dialogs/signatureStatus...
Tracing app...
Tracing actions/actions...
Tracing application/application...
Tracing common/checkbox...
Tracing common/home...
Tracing chat/chat...
Tracing customer/banking...
Tracing customer/customerDisplay...
Tracing customer/employment...
Tracing customer/extended...
Tracing customer/income...
Tracing customer/personal...
Tracing customersnapshot/customerSnapshot...
Tracing flags/flags...
Tracing lead/banking...
Tracing lead/employment...
Tracing lead/extended...
Tracing lead/income...
Tracing lead/leadDisplay...
Tracing lead/personal...
Tracing loanmarks/loanMarks...
Tracing loans/loans...
Tracing login/login...
Tracing notes/notes...
Tracing savedbanks/savedBanks...
Tracing testFolder/testShowData...
Tracing tickets/tickets...
Tracing resources/dialogs/addNote...
Tracing resources/dialogs/ebureau...
Tracing resources/dialogs/followUp...
Tracing resources/dialogs/incentives...
Tracing resources/dialogs/previousAppDetails...
Tracing resources/dialogs/prompt...
Tracing resources/dialogs/signatureStatus...
Tracing resources/dialogs/supportTicket...
Tracing resources/dialogs/tooltip...
Tracing resources/dialogs/transition...
Tracing aurelia-bootstrapper...
Tracing aurelia-history-browser...
Tracing aurelia-loader-default...
Tracing aurelia-logging-console...
Tracing aurelia-pal-browser...
Tracing aurelia-templating-binding...
Tracing text...
Tracing aurelia-templating-resources...
Tracing aurelia-templating-router...
Tracing aurelia-testing...
Tracing bootstrap...
Tracing bootstrap/css/bootstrap...
Failed to write the bundle
Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated     position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:276:15)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:110:12)
    at C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:60:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:157:14)
    at Concat.add (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:58:18)
    at work.then (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\bundle.js:207:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
{ uid: 13,
  name: 'writeBundles',
  branch: false,
  error: Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated     position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:276:15)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:110:12)
    at C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:60:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:157:14)
    at Concat.add (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:58:18)
    at work.then (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\bundle.js:207:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7),
  duration: [ 2, 119329046 ],
  time: 1515005810432 }
{ uid: 1,
  name: '<series>',
  branch: true,
  error: Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated     position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:276:15)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:110:12)
    at C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:60:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:157:14)
    at Concat.add (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:58:18)
    at work.then (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\bundle.js:207:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7),
  duration: [ 4, 175263924 ],
  time: 1515005810433 }
{ uid: 0,
  name: '<series>',
  branch: true,
  error: Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated     position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:276:15)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:110:12)
    at C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:60:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:157:14)
    at Concat.add (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:58:18)
    at work.then (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\bundle.js:207:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7),
  duration: [ 4, 177157338 ],
  time: 1515005810434 }
Error: original.line and original.column are not numbers -- you probably meant to omit the original mapping entirely and only map the generated     position. If so, pass null for the original mapping instead of an object with empty or null values.
    at SourceMapGenerator_validateMapping [as _validateMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:276:15)
    at SourceMapGenerator_addMapping [as addMapping] (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-generator.js:110:12)
    at C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:60:28
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (    C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:157:14)
    at Concat.add (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\concat-with-sourcemaps\index.js:58:18)
    at work.then (C:\Users\charbaugh\Source\Repos\WebUi3\node_modules\aurelia-cli\lib\build\bundle.js:207:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

If we change the sourcemaps option in the aurelia.json as below then the error goes away, but there are no source maps.

```
"options": {
  "minify": "stage & prod",
  "sourcemaps": "dev & stage"
},

"options": {
  "minify": "stage & prod",
  "sourcemaps": ""
},
```

Comment: What version of the CLI are you running? Is it the latest?

Comment: @AshleyGrant - 0.30.1.  I just tried to update to 0.32.0 and I still got the error.

Comment: What happens if you remove the bootstrap css from your bundle? You'll have to also remove the require element for it (temporarily).

Comment: @AshleyGrant - No change

Comment: What was the last thing that was added or updated on the project?

Comment: Encountered the same problem with webpack-sources. If you're also using webpack, you might want to look into [this discussion here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5931).

Comment: Not that we are aware of - sorry :).  This has happened on separate aurelia apps we've created as well.